# How can I jump to a folder in PHPstorm's project navigration sidebar?

Tags: navigation, phpstorm

I want to find a folder in the project navigation by typing in the location, just like I would when using the "Navigate to file" shortcut. How do I do that? I currently have to scroll and click on each folder to get to the place I want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well -- **you still can use `Navigate | File...` for folders** -- you just have to use "/" or "\" at the end to specify that you want to see folders (works in PhpStorm v8).

---

Another solution (for **frequently** used folders) -- mark it as favorite. You can then optionally use standard <kbd>Alt+F1, 1</kbd> (`Navigate | Select In... | Project View`) to locate it in Project View panel.

---

For **very frequently** used folders -- you can just bookmark it (but not ordinary bookmark -- mnemonic bookmark instead -- it will associate a letter or digit with it).

Comment: Wonderful, wasn't aware that ending the File search with a "/" opened the folder in the tree. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution I found is to double click on the folder in the Navigation Bar.